# wildfly 16 and the warning 'com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIHelper is deprecated from CDI 1.1!'

Tags: wildfly, cdi, mojarra

I am seeing this warning in Wildfly 16:

```
17:28:43,353 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-4) WELD-000146: BeforeBeanDiscovery.addAnnotatedType(AnnotatedType<?>) used for class com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIHelper is deprecated from CDI 1.1!
```

I see the following post here: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/280071

is there some way on how to get rid of this warning, using the Spring Framework 3.x.

best

Comment: Can you add your code base to check on wildfly 16 ?